# Holy priest professions for the most beneficial self applied stat boosts

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Typically elitist jerks will cover professions that are best for a particular spec/class and by best, this is not a matter of opinion, best here is defined as the benefits the individual gets from mastering a profession such as being able to use +67 agility gems that my combat rogue is able to make from being a jewel crafter.

My priest is in holy spec. I'm curious if anyone knows offhand what professions will allow me to maximize critical stats if I go ahead and take the time to master them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely Blacksmithing (since you can use epic gems and get +100 intellect instead of +80 from other professions) and Tailoring (for the on proc intellect or spirit cloak enchant).

If you didn't want to go with Tailoring then likely the next choice would be Jewelcrafting, as you can get +81 of a stat out of using Jewelcrafting gems, rather than +80 from the other professions.

Keep in mind however, with Mists of Pandaria coming out before the end of the year this will soon change.

Comment: That's a shame. I was hoping engineering would be one of them. :-) I've always wanted to level that one but couldn't statistically back it up.

Comment: Engineering is usually reasonable at the start of an expansion for the items you can make, and is more of a utility profession for the rest of the expansion

Comment: Your critical stat as a priest is Intellect. That said, engineering has on use bonus to gloves ([Synapse Springs](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=82175)) that provides a 480 bonus to your highest primary stat. Though this works out to be about 80~ passively if you use the cool down every time its up. I'd personally pick Leatherworking, combined with either tailoring or inscription if you are wanting highest primary stat.